# Android studio - couldn't resolve @id/default_state - Rendering problems

Tags: android, xml

I have this problems when I try to add the Fab in my xml code but I don't understand why..I tried to clean my project and invalid cache and restart but nothing changes.

This is my xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/left_drawer_activity_tickets"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"

        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

            android:id="@+id/appbar_activity"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_activity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <SearchView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:id="@+id/search_activity"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:queryHint="Search..."
                android:visibility="gone"
                />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#DDDDDD"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"


            >



            <it.prova.widgets.AnimatedExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewTickets"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>








        <io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
            android:id="@+id/fab_option_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"

            app:fabGravity="bottom_end"
            app:fabMenu="@menu/fab_speed_dial_tickets_minimal"
            app:miniFabBackgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:miniFabDrawableTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:miniFabTitleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>





    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_right_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_right_customer"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_right_customer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view_left_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_left_drawer" />
```

How can I do?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Fab that I used is [this](https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial)

Comment: Why? You use two drawerLayout?

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu Yes, I want to use left and right drawer

Comment: Try remove xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android". Just call it in Layout Root

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu Ok, I tried but I still have the error..

Comment: Pretty sure it's a problem with yavski's FAB itself. Works fine on the emulator/real device, but the preview can't handle it.

Comment: I cut and paste my code and it works for now, I hope updating AS in future will resolve this problem, thanks you @DavidLord

Comment: FYI, it's recently been reported on the project's GH page: https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the [FAB-Speed-Dial library by yavski](https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial). I experienced a similar [issue](https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial/issues/32) to do with default_state and error messages in Logcat. The two are related.

The author is going to rectify these in a future update. For now what you can do is add in an empty default constructor to `FabSpeedDialBehaviour.java` as noted in issue 32. However, it might be easier waiting for the update. Track issue 32 to see when it will land. It will also fix issue 11.